# Sent mail with attachment in Codeigniter to multiple list

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

With below code its work fine. $maillist is my list in with member with email.
Now problem when i run this. member receive multiple attachment as list move forward.

like my second member receive two attachment[same attachment] third receice three and so on.

Your help will really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance
Prashant.

```
$path_to_the_file = "/data/mail-attachment/";
                $attachfile = $path_to_the_file.$mailinfo->attachment;

                //SET COMMON VARIABLES
                $fromname = "helpdesk@domainname.com";
                $subjectline = $mailinfo->subjectline;
                $this->load->library('email');
                $message = $mailinfo->mailbody;
                $message .= "<br /><br /><a href=\"$attachfile\">Download Attachment</a>";

                foreach ($maillist as $key => $value) 
                {
                    $emailto = $value->email;

                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                    $this->email->from($fromname);      // change it to yours
                    $this->email->to($emailto);         // change it to yours
                    $this->email->subject($subjectline);
                    $this->email->message($message);
                    $this->email->attach($attachfile);
                    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

                    if($this->email->send()) { 
                        $success_mail_count++;
                    }       
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.....
You meed to pass `clear(TRUE)` to clear attached file after mail send.

```
        path_to_the_file = "/data/mail-attachment/";
        $attachfile = $path_to_the_file . $mailinfo->attachment;

        //SET COMMON VARIABLES
        $fromname = "helpdesk@domainname.com";
        $subjectline = $mailinfo->subjectline;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $message = $mailinfo->mailbody;
        $message .= "<br /><br /><a href=\"$attachfile\">Download Attachment</a>";
        $emailto = array();
        foreach ($maillist as $key => $value) {
            $emailto = $value->email;
        }
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($fromname);   // change it to yours
        $this->email->to($emailto);   // change it to yours
        $this->email->subject($subjectline);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach($attachfile);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            $this->email->clear(TRUE);
            $success_mail_count++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Nikhil it work. One more help will be thankfull. Can I change the  attachment file name before sent..??

Comment: Try this `$this->email->attach('file name.pdf', 'attachment', 'new file name.pdf');`